# $SU(2)$ in two complex dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, group-theory

I am just a beginner of group theory. I saw an $SU(2)$ example (example 4.16) in the book by Nadir Jeevanjee, An introduction to Tensors and group theory for Physicists. For $SU(2)$ elements, they satisfy:

$$A^{\dagger}=A^{-1}.$$

The generic element is:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
\alpha\ \ \beta\\
-\bar{\beta}\ \bar{\alpha} 
\end{pmatrix}
,\ \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}
,\ |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1.
$$

The author just directly write one kind of parametrization:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i(\psi+\phi)/2}\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}\ \ ie^{i(\psi-\phi)/2}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}\\
ie^{-i(\psi-\phi)/2}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}\ \ e^{-i(\psi+\phi)/2}\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The three angles $\theta,\psi,\phi$ are Euler angles. From $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$, I can get a 3-sphere.

If $\alpha=u+iv,\ \beta=x+iy$, I get: $u^2+v^2+x^2+y^2=1.$ I can use a parametrization:

$$
u=\cos{\phi_1}\\
v=\sin{\phi_1}\cos{\phi_2}\\
x=\sin{\phi_1}\sin{\phi_2}\cos{\phi_3}\\
y=\sin{\phi_1}\sin{\phi_2}\sin{\phi_3}.
$$
But apparently this is not the case which is related to Euler angles. How can I get the parametrization by the author and relate to the Euler angles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the “usual” Euleurian expression as the product $R_z(\zeta)R_y(\eta)R_z(\gamma)$, with
$$
R_k(\varphi)=e^{i\varphi \sigma_k}
$$
you need to set
\begin{align}
\zeta=\psi+\pi/4\, ,\qquad \gamma=\phi-\pi/4\, ,\qquad 
\eta=\theta\, .
\end{align}
The rest you can read off:
$$
\alpha=e^{i(\psi+\phi)}\cos\theta/2 = \cos\left((\psi+\phi)/2\right)\cos(\theta/2) + i 
\sin\left((\psi+\phi)/2\right)\cos(\theta/2)
$$
so $u=\cos\left((\psi+\phi)/2\right)\cos\theta/2$ etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!